# create word search puzzle using jquery for non english characters

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to create a word search puzzle game using this

http://jsfiddle.net/sirmarcio/jtn0mchd/

this is the problem area

```
$(document).ready( function () {
    var words = "Raúl,María,heißt,TOUCH";
    $("#cuadricula").wordsearchwidget({"wordlist" : words,"gridsize" : 10});
});
```

i am not pasting whole code as it is available on JSfiddle, its not my code i am just using it for reference

and referring this

[Placing words in table grid in word search puzzle?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8215919/placing-words-in-table-grid-in-word-search-puzzle)

as you can see i am trying few non english words, while words like 
Raúl,María work properly

```
heißt
```

ends up as HEISST ,

does javascript and for that matter jquery support such words , and how can i use heißt as it is, any reference so that these words donot end up splitting the way they are.

Comment: I'm not sure there's a simple answer to your question. [This article](http://alistapart.com/article/accent-folding-for-auto-complete) is a great read on 'accent folding` and also discusses some of  the challenges in doing something like what you would like. HTH

Comment: thanks for the help atleast got a headsup on a way to go

Answer (score 0):

The HTTP headers must indicate UTF-8, if you are using UTF-8.

This appears to be a problem with jsfiddle not recognizing that you have UTF-8 in your copy/paste snippet and then sending you the JS responses without the header.

Naturally, if you have problems with headers, you're not going to want to be testing it using third party vendors, definitely not jsfiddle, at least.